# intento deployear mi site en netlify desde argentina pero me sale error 404

Tags: error404, 404

[image]

en mi computadora y otras funciona perfecto, pero cada vez que intento deployear un proyecto en netlify me aparece un error 404, no solo con este, si sirve la info, estoy importando mi proyecto desde github

Comment: Estas subiendo la carpeta que te crea luego de correr **npm run build** dentro de netlify?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: estoy deployeando un projecto de django, no creo que npm run build funcione o no? No se absolutamente nada de netlify pero vi que a muchas personas de argentina tmbn les pasaba